# Location manager stops working after some interval in background

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, location

I m developing an app in which I have to track the `LocationUpdate` in the `Background` as well as in the `Foreground` but after some time interval in the `Background` the app stops updating the `Location`.  When I take it back to `Foreground` it starts again and when I put it in background after some time interval it stops again.

I am not able to find the issue please help me if possible.

Comment: What is your desiredAccuracy setting ?

Comment: have you solved your problem? What was the cause? How have ypou solved it? You may answer you own question, this may help others.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify that your app need location updates when in background in `plist`

[image]

Here is apple docs [Getting Location Events in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10)

and here is a [tutorial for this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/).

And I would recommend you to read [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i have done this in my plist. The Problem is basically it updates for 30-60 minutes than it stops updating location.

Comment: it might be due to large value of distance filter.

Comment: I have used distance filter value equal to 10m.

Answer (score 0):

- disable distance filter
- set desired Accuracy to best
- use - (void)startUpdatingLocation

Now in ios6: there is

```
locationManager:didUpdateLocations:
```

in ios5 there is

```
locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:
```

the first delivers the locations buffered in the background  and keeps your application sleeping and wakes it up with a sequence of fixes, while the ios5 method delivers the location all of the time.

Comment: As i m using ios6 so how fix it up to get location update of every move in background.

Comment: after that hours, do you loose the positions while in background, or do you get them to late?

Comment: i loose the positions while in background when comes in the foreground it again start updating from the current location. So how do i keep it updating while in the background

Comment: this is interesting, check again if you have disabled all filters,  use desiredAccuracyBest, then set app compability to ios 5, and use the ios 5 method. further install an foreign GPS app, like Motion-X GPS and check if they can record a track while in background.

Comment: i have set distance filter value is 0.0 and accuracy to best while in background but still the app stops updating after some time

Comment: Install Motion-X GPS and test with that, If that works, it is your fault,  otherwise there is another defect.